# Need help figuring out syntax for a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

basically, i need a query that looks mostly like this...

```
SELECT column FROM tablename WHERE column LIKE '%images/uploads%';
```

There only catch here is, that I only want a return where anything after uploads is ok as long as it's NOT a forward slash `/`

So, `images/uploads/somethingelse` is NOT what i'm looking for

`images/uploadssomethingelse`  IS what i'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to reject `images/uploadssomethingelse/somethingelse`?

Comment: idealy i'd like to find and replace it. Long story short i did a find and replace but neglected to add the / after the uploads. So not i can just search for images/uploads because the results will include way more entries than i need.

Answer (score 2):

This would help you

```
SELECT column FROM tablename WHERE column LIKE '%images/uploads%' AND column NOT LIKE '%images/uploads/%';`
```

Comment: Ah, that worked like a charm... I feel stupid for not thinking of this haha. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
    column LIKE '%images/uploads%' 
and column not like '%images/uploads%/%';
```

Comment: well this is what he asked for: `where anything after uploads is ok as long as it's NOT a forward slash /`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column FROM tablename WHERE column REGEXP 'images/uploads[^/]*$';
```